Math delimiters and assistive MML in MathJax config file
I try to follow the instructions in the official MathJax documentation as vanilla as possible.  What I want is that I can use the original style "$" and "$$" and also the new style "\(" and "\[" math delimiters.  I also do not want assistive MML and I think I suppose that is what we see when we right-click on math elements, then a menu appears and this menu gives possibilities to show pure MML and so on.  But with the same script I get also that menu.  I let my script also be inspired by the official 3.2 MathJax documentation.  The relevant portions of my code are
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-polyfill/7.10.4/polyfill.min.js?features=es6"></script>
  <script> 
    MathJax = {
      tex: {
        inlineMath: [
          ["\(", "\)"] ,
          ['$', '$'],
          
        ],
        displayMath: [
          ["$$", "$$"],
          ["\[", "\]"]
        ]
      },
      MathML: {
        extensions: ["content-mathml.js"]
      },
      options: {
        menuOptions: {
          settings: {
            assistiveMml: false, // true to enable assistive MathML
          }
        }
      }
  };
</script>
  <script id="MathJax-script" async="" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-chtml.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
\(a\), \(b\) and $c$  
we have that
\[ c^2 = a^2 + b^2. \] 
or
$$
c^2 = a^2 + b^2.
$$ 
and $a$
</body>

The output that I see is not what I expected.  Here follows an image of the output.

I can use assistive MML and this is also which I do not want.  I used the last versions of FireFox and Chrome to test. I test with the latest MathJax 3. I tried to rename the variable "MathJax" in "MathJax.config" and also "Window.MathJax".  I used different quotes etc.  I seem to run out of possibilities.  Nevertheless, I see example files of MathJax on github with quite the same configuration. And they seem to manage.  I am looking for suggestions.

In Javascript, "\(" is the same as "(". You must double the backslashes in the MathJax configuration statement.

Thank you!  I am quite sure though, that I did not see these escaped escapes in the docs.  But I can be mistaken.  Is the code for avoiding assistive MML OK?
